# ReImporting a module after deleting it

Tags: python, import

**I want to understand how import works**

I imported a module named **funcs** as **import funcs**

It printed a line **"funcs print"** that was in **funcs** module

I deleted it's bytecode file and did **del funcs** to unimport it

I again imported it but this time it didn't print **"funcs print"**

Why what's the reason.

I know what **reload(funcs)** does but want to understand **import** after using **del**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what exactly did you do to "delete the bytecode". did you just do `del funcs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try this in your Python shell:

```
>>> import sys
>>> "funcs" in sys.modules
False
>>> import funcs
funcs print
>>> "funcs" in sys.modules
True
>>> sys.modules["funcs"] is funcs
True
>>> del funcs
>>> "funcs" in sys.modules
True
>>> sys.modules["funcs"]
<module 'funcs' form 'funcs.pyc'>
>>> del sys.modules["funcs"]
>>> import funcs
funcs print
```

To make a long story short, `import` first check if the module is already loaded (in `sys.modules`) and only loads it if it's not.

Comment: u want to say that main registery for modules is sys.modules??